# OpenLayers 2 trigger event when baselayer changes

Tags: event-handling, openlayers

I want my application to do something when the base layer has changed.

Is it possible to handle/catch that event in OpenLayers 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
map.events.register("changebaselayer", this, function (obj) {
    if (obj.layer.name == 'layer_name') {
       //do something if new base layer is equal to layer_name
       ....
   }
});
```

You can see all the possible events you can hook into in the [source for OpenLayers/Map.js](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js) although the actual event will be triggered by the LayerSwitcher.